# Boosting matched documents in Elasticsearch which have a certain tag

Tags: search, lucene, elasticsearch

I have an index of documents that look this:

```
{
    url: "/foo/bar",
    html_blocks: [
       "<h1>hi</h1>"
    ],
    tags: [
        "video",
        "text"
    ],
    title: "My title"
}
```

I'd like to query these documents on the *title* and *html_blocks* fields, and for any matches add a boost if they have a *video* tag.

So far, my query looks like this:

```
{
    "query": {
        "query_string": {
            "query": "foo",
            "fields": [
                "title",
                "html_blocks"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

How do I modify it so that it continues to **only return results if a match is found in the existing query**, but a boost is added to any of the results which have a *video* tag? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want a custom_filters_score which will just boost on matches. Note that filter input is not analyzed, so you might wrap that in a query if you need it analyzed. Your other options to boost, while not really for this case are the boosting query, which is good for demoting results and the custom_score_query which is good for added boosts based on some calculated value.

See: [Custom_filters_score](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/custom-filters-score-query/)

```
{
    "query": {
        "custom_filters_score": {
            "query": {
                "query_string": {
                    "query": "foo",
                    "fields": [
                        "title",
                        "html_blocks"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "filters": [
                {
                    "filter": {
                        "term": {
                            "tags": "video"
                        }
                    },
                    "boost": 3
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Edit:

This is what I mean by wrapping in a query using a filter query. Trust me, once you get the hang of ES, you'll be nested so knee deep that you'll produce some of the most satisfying queries ever.

```
{
    "query": {
        "custom_filters_score": {
            "query": {
                "query_string": {
                    "query": "foo",
                    "fields": [
                        "title",
                        "html_blocks"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "filters": [
                {
                    "filter": {
                        //here comes the filter query, and I changed term to match
                        //since match analyzes
                        "query":{                          
                            "match": {
                                "tags": "video"
                            }
                         }
                    },
                    "boost": 3
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, if you don't mind explaining how to wrap the filter in a query, I'm not quite clear on that. Were you referencing 'fquery'? http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/query-filter/

Comment: No problem. Edit above and, yes, that is the bit I was referencing.